# Selected time periods of IB data for data analysis

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon all,

The below script captures Initial Balance (first highest and lowest price within the first 60 mins) for market opening times (London, New York and Asia).

The building of IB happens within the first 60 mins and is displayed thereafter, so for example London 0800 to 0900 IB builds and displays 0900 onwards.

The script then looks at the three IB highs and works out the highest and plots this (displayed as a white line in the below script).

What I am trying to work out is how do I exclude the building phase of the new IB coming into play. The below pictures should help explain this:

[image]
How would I exclude the IB building phase for the blue plot, during that 1 hour the purple and yellow would only be included in the calculation and the white line would continue at the height on the highest excluding the IB build.

I can explain further if required. Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Please see script so far:

```
//@version=4
study("Highest Test Script", overlay=true)


offset_val = input(title="Daily Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=10)
offset_valW = input(title="Weekly Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=30)



// Asia Start
time_int_01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia", input.session)

in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)

plot(not in_time_int_01 ? highe_01 : na, title="Asia High", color=color.purple, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_01 ? highe_01 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia/UTC High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia/UTC High")

plot(not in_time_int_01 ? lowe_01  : na, title="Asia Low",  color=color.purple,  linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_01 ? lowe_01 : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia/UTC Low",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia/UTC Low")
// Asia Finish


// London Start
time_int_02 = input("0800-0900:1234567", "London", input.session)
time_int_002 = input("0900-0800:1234567", "London", input.session)

in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)

var highe_02 = 0.0
var lowe_02  = 10e10
if in_time_int_02
    if not in_time_int_02[1]
        highe_02 := high
        lowe_02  := low
    else
        highe_02 := max(high, highe_02)
        lowe_02  := min(low, lowe_02)

plot(not in_time_int_02 ? highe_02 : na, title="London High", color=color.yellow, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_02 ? highe_02 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London High")

plot(not in_time_int_02 ? lowe_02  : na, title="London Low",  color=color.yellow,  linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_02 ? lowe_02  : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London Low",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London Low")
// London Finsh


// New York Start
time_int_03 = input("1430-1530:1234567", "New York", input.session)

in_time_int_03 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_03)

var highe_03 = 0.0
var lowe_03  = 10e10
if in_time_int_03
    if not in_time_int_03[1]
        highe_03 := high
        lowe_03  := low
    else
        highe_03 := max(high, highe_03)
        lowe_03  := min(low, lowe_03)

plot(not in_time_int_03 ? highe_03 : na, title="New York High", color=color.blue, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_03 ? highe_03 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York High")

plot(not in_time_int_03 ? lowe_03  : na, title="New York Low",  color=color.blue,  linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_03 ? lowe_03  : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York Low",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York Low")
// New York Finish


//Londontest = (not time_int_002 ? highe_02 : na)

//DailyIBHighest = max(highe_01, Londontest, highe_03)

DailyIBHighest = max(highe_01, highe_02, highe_03)

plot(DailyIBHighest, color=color.white, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

#####Update 18/02/2021 @ 1600 #####

After thinking about this question further, what I am trying to achieve is to work out the max IB high as detailed below:

**0000 - 0100**

Yellow - highe_02

Blue - highe_03

**0100 - 0800**

Yellow - highe_02

Blue - highe_03

Purple - highe_01

**0800 - 0900**

Blue - highe_03

Purple - highe_01

**0900 - 1430**

Yellow - highe_02

Blue - highe_03

Purple - highe_01

**1430 - 1530**

Yellow - highe_02

Purple - highe_01

**1530 - 0000**

Yellow - highe_02

Blue - highe_03

Purple - highe_01

**##### Update 19/02/2021 @ 0845 ####**

I have made the original IBs high/low as false within setting can be switched on to confirm the redlines are aligned correctly. This is how I would like it displayed but I feel I haven't gone the right way about it as I would like to consolidate the output red line into one output so that I can use it for alerts.

```
//@version=4
study("Highest Test Script", overlay=true)


offset_val = input(title="Daily Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=10)
offset_valW = input(title="Weekly Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=30)
ShowIB = input(false, title="show IBs")


// Asia Start
time_int_01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia", input.session)
time_int_001 = input("0100-0000:1234567", "London", input.session)

in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)
in_time_int_001 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_001)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)

plot(not in_time_int_01  and ShowIB ? highe_01 : na, title="Asia High", color=color.purple, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_01  and ShowIB ? highe_01 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia/UTC High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia/UTC High")

plot(not in_time_int_01  and ShowIB ? lowe_01  : na, title="Asia Low",  color=color.purple,  linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_01  and ShowIB ? lowe_01 : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia/UTC Low",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia/UTC Low")
// Asia Finish


// London Start
time_int_02 = input("0800-0900:1234567", "London", input.session)
time_int_002 = input("0900-0800:1234567", "London", input.session)

in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)
in_time_int_002 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_002)


var highe_02 = 0.0
var lowe_02  = 10e10
if in_time_int_02
    if not in_time_int_02[1]
        highe_02 := high
        lowe_02  := low
    else
        highe_02 := max(high, highe_02)
        lowe_02  := min(low, lowe_02)

plot(not in_time_int_02  and ShowIB ? highe_02 : na, title="London High", color=color.yellow, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_02  and ShowIB ? highe_02 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London High")

plot(not in_time_int_02  and ShowIB ? lowe_02  : na, title="London Low",  color=color.yellow,  linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_02  and ShowIB ? lowe_02  : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London Low",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London Low")
// London Finsh


// New York Start
time_int_03 = input("1430-1530:1234567", "New York", input.session)
time_int_003 = input("1530-1430:1234567", "New York", input.session)

in_time_int_03 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_03)
in_time_int_003 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_003)

var highe_03 = 0.0
var lowe_03  = 10e10
if in_time_int_03
    if not in_time_int_03[1]
        highe_03 := high
        lowe_03  := low
    else
        highe_03 := max(high, highe_03)
        lowe_03  := min(low, lowe_03)

plot(not in_time_int_03  and ShowIB ? highe_03 : na, title="New York High", color=color.blue, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_03 and ShowIB ? highe_03 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York High")

plot(not in_time_int_03 and ShowIB ? lowe_03  : na, title="New York Low",  color=color.blue,  linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_03 and ShowIB ? lowe_03  : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York Low",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York Low")
// New York Finish



Session01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "0000 - 0100", input.session)
S1 = time(timeframe.period, Session01)

Session02 = input("0100-0800:1234567", "0100 - 0800", input.session)
S2 = time(timeframe.period, Session02)

Session03 = input("0800-0900:1234567", "0800 - 0900", input.session)
S3 = time(timeframe.period, Session03)

Session04 = input("0900-1430:1234567", "0900 - 1430", input.session)
S4 = time(timeframe.period, Session04)

Session05 = input("1430-1530:1234567", "1430 - 1530", input.session)
S5 = time(timeframe.period, Session05)

Session06 = input("1530-0000:1234567", "1530 - 0000", input.session)
S6 = time(timeframe.period, Session06)

Test1 = S2 or S4 or S6 ? max(highe_01, highe_02, highe_03) : na
Test2 = S5 ? max(highe_02, highe_01) : na
Test3 = S1 ? max(highe_02, highe_03) : na
Test4 = S3 ? max(highe_03, highe_01) : na

Test1a = S2 or S4 or S6 ? min(lowe_01, lowe_02, lowe_03) : na
Test2a = S5 ? min(lowe_02, lowe_01) : na
Test3a = S1 ? min(lowe_02, lowe_03) : na
Test4a = S3 ? min(lowe_03, lowe_01) : na


plot(Test1, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test2, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test3, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test4, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)

plot(Test1a, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test2a, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test3a, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test4a, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Is there a way to put the below extract into a var or function? Just seems to much code, I feel I have not completed it correctly.

```
Session01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "0000 - 0100", input.session)
S1 = time(timeframe.period, Session01)

Session02 = input("0100-0800:1234567", "0100 - 0800", input.session)
S2 = time(timeframe.period, Session02)

Session03 = input("0800-0900:1234567", "0800 - 0900", input.session)
S3 = time(timeframe.period, Session03)

Session04 = input("0900-1430:1234567", "0900 - 1430", input.session)
S4 = time(timeframe.period, Session04)

Session05 = input("1430-1530:1234567", "1430 - 1530", input.session)
S5 = time(timeframe.period, Session05)

Session06 = input("1530-0000:1234567", "1530 - 0000", input.session)
S6 = time(timeframe.period, Session06)

Test1 = S2 or S4 or S6 ? max(highe_01, highe_02, highe_03) : na
Test2 = S5 ? max(highe_02, highe_01) : na
Test3 = S1 ? max(highe_02, highe_03) : na
Test4 = S3 ? max(highe_03, highe_01) : na

Test1a = S2 or S4 or S6 ? min(lowe_01, lowe_02, lowe_03) : na
Test2a = S5 ? min(lowe_02, lowe_01) : na
Test3a = S1 ? min(lowe_02, lowe_03) : na
Test4a = S3 ? min(lowe_03, lowe_01) : na


plot(Test1, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test2, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test3, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test4, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)

plot(Test1a, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test2a, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test3a, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Test4a, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to achieve my goal below is the final code.

@AnyDozer I would be grateful if you could cast your eyes over the code for suggested comments.

```
//@version=4
study("Initial Balance Markets Time Zones - Modified", overlay=true)

// User adjustment inputs
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=30)
backcolor = input(true, title="Optional background colour Price Action (PA) above or below all IB highs/lows")
DisplayAllIBs = input(false, title="Optional to display all IB highs/lows")


// Asia START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Start
time_int_01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Finish

//////////////////////////////////// Asia Plot Start
//High
AsiaIBHighInput = input('0100-0101:1234567', title="Capture Asia IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in

AsiaIBHigh = time("1", AsiaIBHighInput)

var AsiaIBHighPA = 0.0
if AsiaIBHigh
    if not AsiaIBHigh[1]
        AsiaIBHighPA := highe_01

plotAsiaIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBHighPA : na, title=" Asia IB High", color=color.purple, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia IB High")

//Low
AsiaIBLowInput = input('0100-0101:1234567', title="Capture Asia IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in

AsiaIBLow = time("1", AsiaIBLowInput)

var AsiaIBLowPA = 0.0
if AsiaIBLow
    if not AsiaIBLow[1]
        AsiaIBLowPA := lowe_01

plotAsiaIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBLowPA : na, title=" Asia IB Low", color=color.purple, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia IB Low")
//////////////////////////////////// Asia Plot Finish
// Asia FINISH //



// London START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance London Start
time_int_02 = input("0800-0900:1234567", "London IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)

var highe_02 = 0.0
var lowe_02  = 10e10
if in_time_int_02
    if not in_time_int_02[1]
        highe_02 := high
        lowe_02  := low
    else
        highe_02 := max(high, highe_02)
        lowe_02  := min(low, lowe_02)
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance London Finsh

//////////////////////////////////// London Plot Start
//High
LonIBHighInput = input('0900-0901:1234567', title="Capture London IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in

LonIBHigh = time("1", LonIBHighInput)

var LonIBHighPA = 0.0
if LonIBHigh
    if not LonIBHigh[1]
        LonIBHighPA := highe_02

plotLonIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBHighPA : na, title=" Lon IB High", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Lon IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Lon IB High")

//Low
LonIBLowInput = input('0900-0901:1234567', title="Capture London IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in

LonIBLow = time("1", LonIBLowInput)

var LonIBLowPA = 0.0
if LonIBLow
    if not LonIBLow[1]
        LonIBLowPA := lowe_02

plotLonIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBLowPA : na, title=" Lon IB Low", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Lon IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Lon IB Low")
//////////////////////////////////// London Plot Finish
// London FINISH //



// New York START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance New York Start
time_int_03 = input("1430-1530:1234567", "New York IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_03 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_03)

var highe_03 = 0.0
var lowe_03  = 10e10
if in_time_int_03
    if not in_time_int_03[1]
        highe_03 := high
        lowe_03  := low
    else
        highe_03 := max(high, highe_03)
        lowe_03  := min(low, lowe_03)
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance New York Finish

//////////////////////////////////// New York Plot Start
//High
NYIBHighInput = input('1530-1531:1234567', title="Capture New York IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in

NYIBHigh = time("1", NYIBHighInput)

var NYIBHighPA = 0.0
if NYIBHigh
    if not NYIBHigh[1]
        NYIBHighPA := highe_03

plotNYIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBHighPA : na, title=" New York IB High", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York IB High")

//Low
NYIBLowInput = input('1530-1531:1234567', title="Capture New York IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in

NYIBLow = time("1", NYIBLowInput)

var NYIBLowPA = 0.0
if NYIBLow
    if not NYIBLow[1]
        NYIBLowPA := lowe_03

plotNYIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBLowPA : na, title=" New York IB Low", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York IB Low")
//////////////////////////////////// New York Plot Finish
// New York FINISH //


// Background colors
AsiaAboveHigh = close>(AsiaIBHighPA)
LondonAboveHigh = close>(LonIBHighPA)
NewYorkAboveHigh = close>(NYIBHighPA)

Buy = AsiaAboveHigh and LondonAboveHigh and NewYorkAboveHigh
bgcolor(Buy and backcolor ? color.green : na, transp=95, title='Check Chart Buy Signal above all IB Highs')



AsiaBelowLow = close<(AsiaIBLowPA)
LondonBelowLow = close<(LonIBLowPA)
NewYorkBelowLow = close<(NYIBLowPA)

Sell = AsiaBelowLow and LondonBelowLow and NewYorkBelowLow
bgcolor(Sell and backcolor ? color.red : na, transp=95, title='Check Chart Sell Signal below all IB Lows')


// Condition Alerts
alertcondition(Buy==1 ? Buy : na, title="Buy Alert", message="Check Chart Buy Signal above all IB High, {{close}}")
alertcondition(Sell==1 ? Sell :na, title="Sell Alert", message="Check Chart Sell Signal below all IB Low, {{close}}")

AllIBHighest = max(AsiaIBHighPA, LonIBHighPA, NYIBHighPA)
IBHighest = plot(AllIBHighest, title="Highest IB", color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(AllIBHighest, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Highest IB", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Highest IB")


AllIBLowest = min(AsiaIBLowPA, LonIBLowPA, NYIBLowPA)
IBLowest = plot(AllIBLowest, title="Lowest IB", color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(AllIBLowest, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Lowest IB", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Lowest IB")
```

Comment: @AnyDozer your review would be gratefully received.

Comment: Sorry, no comment. I didn't get the gist of the problem.

Comment: @AnyDozer thank you for your time. My goal was to only plot the highest and lowest IBs out of the three market openings. I managed to achieve it, just thought you might have wanted to scan over it. As always thank you for your continued input and support.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got you right this time. Only my design displays a black line instead of a white one.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Highest Test Script)", overlay=true)


offset_val = input(title="Daily Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=10)
offset_valW = input(title="Weekly Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=30)



// Asia Start
time_int_01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia", input.session)

in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)

// London Start
time_int_02 = input("0800-0900:1234567", "London", input.session)
time_int_002 = input("0900-0800:1234567", "London", input.session)

in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)

// New York Start
time_int_03 = input("1430-1530:1234567", "New York", input.session)

in_time_int_03 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_03)

// Asia Start
var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)

plot(not in_time_int_01 and not in_time_int_02 and not in_time_int_03 ? highe_01 : na, title="Asia High", color=color.purple, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_01 ? highe_01 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia/UTC High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia/UTC High")

plot(not in_time_int_01 and not in_time_int_02 and not in_time_int_03 ? lowe_01  : na, title="Asia Low",  color=color.purple,  linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_01 ? lowe_01 : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia/UTC Low",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia/UTC Low")
// Asia Finish


// London Start

var highe_02 = 0.0
var lowe_02  = 10e10
if in_time_int_02
    if not in_time_int_02[1]
        highe_02 := high
        lowe_02  := low
    else
        highe_02 := max(high, highe_02)
        lowe_02  := min(low, lowe_02)

plot(not in_time_int_01 and not in_time_int_02 and not in_time_int_03 ? highe_02 : na, title="London High", color=color.yellow, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_02 ? highe_02 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London High")

plot(not in_time_int_01 and not in_time_int_02 and not in_time_int_03 ? lowe_02  : na, title="London Low",  color=color.yellow,  linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_02 ? lowe_02  : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="London Low",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="London Low")
// London Finsh


// New York Start

var highe_03 = 0.0
var lowe_03  = 10e10
if in_time_int_03
    if not in_time_int_03[1]
        highe_03 := high
        lowe_03  := low
    else
        highe_03 := max(high, highe_03)
        lowe_03  := min(low, lowe_03)

plot(not in_time_int_01 and not in_time_int_02 and not in_time_int_03 ? highe_03 : na, title="New York High", color=color.blue, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_03 ? highe_03 : na, style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York High",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York High")

plot(not in_time_int_01 and not in_time_int_02 and not in_time_int_03 ? lowe_03  : na, title="New York Low",  color=color.blue,  linewidth=3, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(not in_time_int_03 ? lowe_03  : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York Low",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York Low")
// New York Finish


//Londontest = (not time_int_002 ? highe_02 : na)

//DailyIBHighest = max(highe_01, Londontest, highe_03)

DailyIBHighest = max(highe_01, highe_02, highe_03)

plot(DailyIBHighest, color=color.white, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

Comment: Afternoon AnyDozer, thank you for your reply. I have tried the above and it doesn't achieve what I am after. I have been thinking about this and whilst all three IB highs are in play the max() works but when a new IB build is happening during these periods (0000-0100) and (0800-0900) and (1430-1530) the max() only is required for two of the IB highs. Does that make sense. I am still playing trying to work this out.

Comment: Explain again what color lines should remain on the chart in the first hour of the opening of New York.

Comment: AnyDozer I have just updated my answer with additional info. The end result will only have the white line. I have left the other colours on there to ensure what is being coded is true.

Comment: AnyDozer please see a further update within  my question above

Comment: I'm afraid this is beyond me.